# Build all dependencies to one file

Tags: c++

I'm working on a small installer program (silent install of setup, unzipping, ...).

I wondered how to build everything into one .exe file.
I don't even know HOW to search for that correctly.
Could you tell me some keyword to search for?

---

E.g.:

I have **Setup.exe** and **Configs.zip** for my installer to use.

**After compiling** I just wanna have 1 file (**Install.exe**) which **has Setup.exe and Configs.zip included** and can use them.

Comment: c#/whatever dynamically embed resource

Comment: use microsoft setup project and make msi file.

Comment: Google "Windows Installer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use resources that is a normal way to store such files. You can extract that files and execute that than from the temp directory.